# Visual Studio 2012 Can't use web form template

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, templates, web

[image] Hi. I first downloaded visual studio express 2012. I face problem in creating web form. There is no web form option available like the left picture. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In a Visual Studio Command Prompt you need to run the following :

devenv /installvstemplates